# Protractor: How to get value of <input type="number"> with same decimal separator as shown in browser?

Tags: angular, browser, protractor

I have an Angular app which contains `<input type="number">`. That is handy, because the value in there is shown automatically with expected decimal separator (comma) in the browser.
When getting the value with Protractor `element.getAttribute('value')` the value is returned with period as decimal separator.

Shown in browser: 35,2
Value in input: 35.2

Has someone any idea, how to get the shown value 35,2 in my Protrator test?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure how to solve your issue. `.getAttribute()` is definitely the right function to use here. I'm actually curious if you may have found a protractor bug. May be worth opening an issue on github to see if you get a response from the team.

Comment: I'm afraid that it behaves like in W3C recommendation (see https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization.html#2). But nevertheless I need to get the displayed value instead of the value in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below javascript executor for getting the element value

```
var el = element(// your locator here);
var text = browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].text', el);
```

**OR**

```
var text = browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].innerHTML', el);
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work.
The value of the first approach (text) is ```null``` and the value of second approach (innerHTML) is empty.

Comment: Do share your html and the UI for more insights.

Comment: I have a plunker example. I type in the input "35,2" but on button click I get the value "35.2".

Comment: I am not able to enter "35,2" in the input text box example provided.

Comment: I added the lang attribute to the html. Can you enter it now?
https://plnkr.co/edit/7CMYHD9GkJ7CPmmPdsET?p=info

Comment: When you keep `input` type = `number` you will not be able to enter `,` in between the values.

Comment: @StefanieDeutschmann The reason you get `,` instead of `.` is due to the problem with the system language.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this kind of displaying prices in different formats is handled by styles , CSS. And in DOM it will always be in the decimal dot format but in UI it can be any desired format.

Why not you replace the decimal dot to comma after getting the value by getAttribute()

Comment: I'm afraid you're right, it seems to be W3C recommendation (see https://www.ctrl.blog/entry/html5-input-number-localization.html#2). But is there a way to get the displayed value anyway?
The problem with replacing the dot is the following: the requirement I have to test is, that there is a default value set in this input "35,2". So I have to make sure, that exactly this value is shown.

Comment: So when you are reading its value from UI by element.getAttribute('value') and then you replace dot to comma then you are verifying correctly that the default value set in the input is 35,2 only isnt it ?

Comment: I will do it like that, but in addition I need to check also the input type to be "number" as well as the lang set. Only in combination I can be sure, that the value is displayed correctly (german decimal number). Unfortunately I don't see any other way...

Comment: The way you are reading value, you can read the property 'type' as well>>  element.getAttribute('type'). Not sure lang set is also an attribute propert to the same element , if yes then you can read it as well.